# error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'FSharp.Data.Runtime.IJsonDocument' from assembly 'FSharp.Data, Version=2.1.1.0,

Tags: f#

I am working through Evelina Gabasova's Twitter analysis found here: https://github.com/evelinag/Projects/tree/master/Twitter.

I did a nuget restore and now I am getting this exception:

> error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type
>   'FSharp.Data.Runtime.IJsonDocument' from assembly 'FSharp.Data,
>   Version=2.1.1.0,

Can anyone tell me how to think about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internal errors are generally problems with the compiler.  I'd suggest opening a bug.

Comment: Jamie, did you find a solution by now (4 month later) ?

Comment: No.  I never looked back at it.  I would just load the most recent FSILab and start from there

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error with this environment (VS 2013, F# 3.1 12.0.21005.1). My project included a project reference - Interop.Domino.dll and it's working fine until I changed the value in TOOLS -> Options -> F# Tools -> F# Interactive 64-bit F# Interactive from False to True. The error is gone after I changed back the valued from True to False.